# Cropping an image using the largest square that fits starting from the center

Tags: image, shell, ubuntu

Suppose I have an image of size `X*Y`, calling `D = min(X,Y)`, is there an Ubuntu command that allows cropping an image with a square of size `D` centered at `X/2,Y/2`?

I believe `convert` might work, but I can't figure how which flags I can use to do the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageMagick: how to minimally crop an image to a certain aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262466/imagemagick-how-to-minimally-crop-an-image-to-a-certain-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Should be the same as [crop an image to a certain aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262466/imagemagick-how-to-minimally-crop-an-image-to-a-certain-aspect-ratio) with the ratio being 1:1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `D` as the lesser of the width and height like this:

```
D=$(convert input.jpg -format "%[fx:w<h?w:h]" info:)
```

and then crop that size square from the centre like this:

```
convert input.jpg -gravity center -extent "${D}x${D}" result.jpg
```

So, if you start with this 800x400 image:

[image]

You'll get this 400x400 image:

[image]