# How to crop images in same dimension W/H (Ubuntu 16)

Tags: image, command-line, imagemagick, ubuntu-16.04, crop

I have a lot of images of accommodations and restaurants for my webpage, but each images has different sizes. 
For example, I have one image of 300x250 and another one of 550x300.

I want to make squares cropping this images from 300x250 to 250x250 and 300x550 to 300x300 for example.

I find some command to crop images with "imagemagic" but I can't crop as square, centered.

I want to make a copy of all my images squared and then resize all to the same size.

I try with this command but I get "No such file or directory" error.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec bash -c 'convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 ${0%.jpg}  -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100  $0_thumbnail.jpg'  {} \;
```

Now, I can crop images with this code:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec bash -c 'convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 $0  -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100  ${0}_thumb.jpg'  {} \;
```

But cropped image gets this name "X.jpg_thumb.jpg".
How can I modify this command to create X_thumb.jpg filename?

**[SOLVED]**
This command solve my problem "%.*"

```
 find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -printf "%f\n" -exec bash -c 'convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 $0  -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100  ${0%.*}_thumb.jpg'  {} \;
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53660350/2836621

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell but how do I crop recursively all images and rename all to X_thumb.jpg? 
With this code,`find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec bash -c 'convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 $0  -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100  $0'  {} \;` I can modify all my image cropping as I want, but I don't know how to change the name to X_thumb.jpg

Comment: What is `X` please?

Comment: X is the original filename. Like "image.jpg"

Comment: Personally I would advocate using **GNU Parallel** as it splits paths, basenames and extensions simply, avoids quoting and escaping issues and is performant.

Comment: Ok I solve it with this code: ` find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -printf "%f\n" -exec bash -c 'convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 $0  -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100  ${0%.*}_thumb.jpg'  {} \;
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -printf "%f\n" -exec bash -c 'convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 $0  -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100  ${0%.*}_thumb.jpg'  {} \;
```