# Batch edit pictures for album covers on Plex

Tags: linux, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, plex

On a Plex server running on a Debian 11 I have around 100 albums with the wrong aspect ratio cover art. Plex saving the pictures in several subfolders with the name “com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_*”. I wanna edit all of them to be a square without moving their location.

How can I do it from the terminal to crop the pictures in with an aspect ratio of 1:1 without stretching the images or scaling them?
I will do a backup in case the edit break the program.

From [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196399/how-to-batch-resize-all-images-in-a-folder-including-subfolders) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262466/imagemagick-how-to-minimally-crop-an-image-to-a-certain-aspect-ratio) I assume it would be something like this.

```
find . -name 'com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_*' -execdir convert -gravity center -crop_to_aspect_ratio 1:1 {} +
```

But I am getting the error:

> convert-im6.q16: no images defined
> `./com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_d60dd557c42b03a3795a8d6888acc250f7cdbeec'
> @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3229

The images are ca 800px max so the size is not causing the issue.
Anyone did anything similar?

Edit: `find . -name 'com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_*'` returns a list of the Album covers as following:

> ./f/90f4a8c26662a47b63c96f08428ac234984ccfb.bundle/Contents/_combined/posters/com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_6273d593da3e3f94e404622d39219443ff491fdc
> ./f/90f4a8c26662a47b63c96f08428ac234984ccfb.bundle/Uploads/posters/com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_6273d593da3e3f94e404622d39219443ff491fdc
> ./f/ac6989a8ff7a4c4dec6d97246c514f793a96626.bundle/Contents/_stored/posters/com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_13d13e34785396b31469331563de2fa298714e67
> ./f/ac6989a8ff7a4c4dec6d97246c514f793a96626.bundle/Contents/_combined/posters/com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_13d13e34785396b31469331563de2fa298714e67
> ./f/609cc7429f80bd3b06467f770a9723552c685ea.bundle/Contents/_combined/posters/com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_44c9c62fb4976dd078bba17be271cb2cdb76e71a
> ./f/609cc7429f80bd3b06467f770a9723552c685ea.bundle/Uploads/posters/com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_44c9c62fb4976dd078bba17be271cb2cdb76e71a

note that images have no extentions. this is checked again through the Files app through searching for 'com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_' and ensuring all results are pictures and all without extentins.

[image]

Comment: So what does `find . -name 'com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_*'` return, are you getting image file names?

Comment: it does returns a list of the image files similar to 'com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_d60dd557c42b03a3795a8d6888acc250f7cdbeec'.  The images are a mix of PNG and JPG but the files are without an extention. I am guessing this has something to do with the issue?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add the **full** paths of 3-4 images so I can see how they are named.

Comment: I have done that. I checked again through the Files app to ensure that results are all pictures and that all are without extentions. I oppened them and checked their properties.

Comment: Mmm, that's a picture of files rather than textual filenames! Let's take the first one in your picture and try the following command `magick mogrify -gravity centre -crop 1:1  com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_Odfc78f3bbd28a6b739ec9202a7520e07f7f35ea`

Comment: Sorry, I see you are on ancient **ImageMagick** v6, so the command will just be `mogrify -gravity ...` without `magick` prefix.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on  https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- If you use `convert`, you need to supply both an input filename ***and*** an output filename in the format `convert INPUT -gravity ... -crop ... OUTPUT`. If you use `mogrify` it modifies the file in place, so you only need a single filename. You appear to have used `convert` with one filename which will not work.
- You are using `-execdir` rather than `-exec`. I do not know why. The difference is that `execdir` changes directory to the directory containing the file prior to running your command - this appears unnecessary in your case.

So, I think you need to use a command more like the following:

```
find . -type f -name "com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_*" -exec mogrify -gravity center -crop 1:1 {} \;
```

Or, if you really want to use `convert`:

```
find . -type f -name "com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_*" -exec convert {} -gravity center -crop 1:1 {} \;
```